# How to make an Asp.net MVC4 Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

Can someone explain how login works on asp.net mvc? and What's the best way to make it? I want to make a login page where i have to authenticate a user accoding to it's permission. Can someone post a tutorial or a example?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly this question can be easily researched for 5 minutes on google but to each his own. Here is a tutorial from the asp.net site - [Login Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset). This site can be also used for many other questions one might have when starting out development with really anything in asp.net be it web forms, MVC, WebAPI etc. Not really sure exactly what sort of authentication you are shooting for, are you just wanting straight up forms based authentication against the usual ASP.NET Membership provider or if you are going against a Secure Token Service. I believe the tutorial I have listed only covers a most basic scenario. There are more advanced cases that can be found online by simply searching google which will adequately cover login using a third party system like Facebook etc. Good luck and happy development.